# Is there an 'order_save' variable in exp:resso Store?

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to return the total saving for a basket, based on items bought that are on sale. Is this possible?

There's a {you_save} variable per line, but I'd like a total value including quantities to be displayed as "total saving" in the basket - 'order_save' or 'order_saving' would be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the `{order_discount}` variable (which displays the total amount discounted during checkout), Store 2.0.4 adds an `{order_you_save}` variable.

`{order_you_save}` returns the total amount saved by ordering products which are on sale.

https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_204

Comment: Was looking for the exact same thing! Saved my butt today. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `{order_discount}` variable which is avilable in the cart, checkout, and orders tags.

Comment: Well I tried that, but it didn't do what I wanted. To summarise:

On my product listing I have:

1) In store price = {regular_price} which outputs as £2.50
2) Collection price = {sale_price} which outputs as £2.10

If I add that to the basket, I then have:

3) Total price = {order_total} which outputs as £2.50
4) Your Saving = {order_discount} which outputs as £0.00

I need something that outputs bullet point 4 as '40p', which is the total saving in this case based on regular/sale pricing.

Should this work? (sorry for the mess - don't know how to do linebreaks!)

Comment: Oh I misread your initial post the `{order_discount}` tag would be if you were applying a promo_code to your cart. Since you are just using the sale price it would not output a value.

Comment: OK...and no way to achieve it? Seems a pretty useful feature to show what you've saved?

Comment: There isn't a tag that I am aware of currently. You could probably do it with MX Calc and an items loop but obviously that is not ideal. I will add it to the feature request page so we can see about getting it added to a future release.

Comment: OK, I'll try that way for now - thanks for adding it as a feature request.

Comment: This should be fairly easy to add. I'll put it on the list for our next release. In the meantime, MX calc is probably the best solution.